# What is the best way to transfer data from database using curl

Tags: php, mysql, json, curl, php-curl

I have been reading a lot about php CURL and I still couldn't grasp the mechanism of it sending data, it seems that it is not possible to send php array or php object straight away from a database using curl, but it seems to be possible to send the data using JSON as curl return the data as strings, but I have read somewhere that it is possible to make the php array or object as a post data and send it through curl (kinda like ajax I guess). However I have not found the clean and proper tutorial or examples regarding this.

I hope that anyone that has enough knowledge about curl would share an example on how to properly send data, say from from mysql database using curl as an array / object / JSON. Hope it can be useful for anyone looking for ways to send data cross-domain using curl in the future.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

cURL makes HTTP requests. It can make an HTTP request to an HTTP server and it can get an HTTP response from an HTTP server.

It can't communicate with a database. It can communicate with an HTTP server that runs a server side program (which could be written in PHP) which gets data from a database, formats it in an HTTP response and sends that.

An HTTP request or response can include text. A PHP array is not text. A PHP object is not text. JSON is text. The `json_encode` function will convert a PHP array into a JSON text.

Comment: sorry for my language, yes by getting response from database I meant it to call from another php file that retrieve the data from database. So you are telling there's no possible way to send the php array data as an HTTP response using cURL ?

Comment: @Charas — You have to convert it to text … see the last paragraph of the answer which explains how to do that.

Comment: okay thanks, I understand converting it into text (as JSON) and then json_decode($result, true) to get it as an array. I was looking for something like return $array and just got $result as an array without converting it into text. Seems that it is impossible then. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't send the data as array using cURL, So your best bet at this point is to send it using JSON. Which you can do the following way..

```
$data = array("name" => "Hagrid", "age" => "36");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init('http://your-url-to-post-the-data');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

You can also follow the instructions from [POSTing JSON Data With PHP cURL](https://lornajane.net/posts/2011/posting-json-data-with-php-curl)